# Unable to access wordpress login.php

Tags: themes, publish, ftp

I has been completed a theme for a client.  I Used to access the live wp-admin page using

**http://name.myname.com/wp-login.php**

But that page shows just a blank(white) page. How to get fix that?

Note: Their hosting provider is supporting wordpress.

The error now generating is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in /home/mysitee/public_html/mytheme/wp-content/themes/theme name/include/widget.php on line 1
```

Comment: A blank page usually indicates an error of some kind. [Turn on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and edit your question to add any output that that generates.

Comment: @PatJ : I added the error line which is thrown by the webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the content of `theme name/include/widget.php` ?

The error is pointing to line 1 and telling you it did not expect to see `?>` there.

My guess (without seeing the file) is you have closed a php tag instead of opened it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a closing PHP tag where you shouldnt. Perhaps you're missing a bracket or semi-colon in the code a couple lines above.